# How do I tell if zsh is running with privileges?

Tags: zsh, root, privileges

In my .zshrc, I have commands that launch instances of various program, like Mozilla Firefox and Evolution. I obviously do not want to launch them as root so I want to check whether I am root before I launch them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use e.g. such a conditional statement:

```
PRGCMD="firefox"
PRGUSR="user"
if [[ $UID == 0 || $EUID == 0 ]]; then
   # root
   echo Running programm as User $PRGUSR
   sudo -u $PRGUSR ${(z)PRGCMD}
else
   ${(z)PRGCMD}
fi
```

It checks first, if the *real user ID* or the *effective user id* is `zero`, that is `root`.

If so, it uses `sudo` to run the program defined in the variable `PRGCMD` as the user definded in the variable `PRGUSR`. (You can omit this line if you want only the warning message.)

`${(z)PRGCMD}` splits *words as if zsh command line* in case `PRGCMD` contains spaces, i.e. parameters to the program.

A short variant, which only runs the program as non-root is: `[[ $UID != 0 || $EUID != 0 ]] && firefox`

---

Additionally you perhaps want to include `%#` into your prompt, so you can see that your current shell is privileged. From `man zshmisc`:

```
%#     A `#' if the shell is running with privileges, a `%' if not.  Equivalent to `%(!.#.%%)'.  The definition of `privileged', for  these
       purposes,  is that either the effective user ID is zero, or, if POSIX.1e capabilities are supported, that at least one capability is
       raised in either the Effective or Inheritable capability vectors.
```

The code judging if the *shell is running with privileges* (defined in `privasserted()` in `utils.c`) can IMHO not be done in shell code, so if you want the exact same behavior it's probably the best to parse the output of the `%#` prompt expansion:

```
[[ $(print -P "%#") == '#' ]] && echo shell privileged || echo shell not privileged
```

Comment: I thought of this. However, it is possible for the shell to be non-root and still have extra privileges - I would like to do the same check %# in the prompt does.

Comment: @Demetri: I extended my answer to address the behavior of the `%#` prompt expansion.

Comment: @Demetri : I'm curious if the parsing of `print -P "%#"` solved your problem. If yo, please consider to accept my answer `:)`.

Comment: Ah yes, it did solve the problem! Sorry

Comment: Or if you like squiggles: `[[ ${(%):-%#} = \# ]] && echo root`